# St_intersects returning false results in postgis

Tags: postgis, raster

I want to intersect point geometry with raster. In postgis I'm executing

```
  select st_intersects(geom,rast)
  from testraster1,pft_pft
```

and the result is false even though the points are sitting on raster and both have same SRID i.e. 4326. What is the problem?

Comment: You likely need to convert the raster into a geometry.